# how to disable publish button in joomla for author users?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I have three users on my Joomla website
an author who can create content
the editor who can edit content but can not publish
a publisher who can create, edit and publish

the problem is in Joomla is editor also have publish authority but my requirement is I dont want publish authority for author user.
how can i implement that?

Comment: There is a permission in Content ACL for edit state. You should deny that permission from Author.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the confusion in this? If you check this link https://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms. This is another latest link for 2.5 https://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6. Roles are defined as follows

1. Author - **Can create and edit their content.** If you dont want to give edit permission to author you can very well disable it in the content permissions. You will see an **Options** tab on top right when you open contents. After clicking you can go to **Permissions** and give required permissions.
2. Editor - Editor can edit but cannot publish.  **Editor users cannot, publish or change the publishing status of any articles, even their own.**
3. Publisher - This group allows a user to **post, edit and publish any (not just their own) content item from the Front-end**.

Comment: thanks but I don't know how in my Joomla website editor can also publish content. how to disable publish and unpublish option for editor users?

Comment: You can go to contents and then top right options tab and then permissions tab and disable create option for editor. Just allow edit only.

Comment: after disabling create option it just disables create new article option after editor login it does not disable publish or unpublish options. I want to disable publish and unpublish option for editor after editor login from backend

Comment: one more question how to allow edit permission to the editor for the specific category as it showing locked when I enable edit option for the editor in the permission tab in category?